Unable to establish the reason for failure of SVG payload’s failure to load from GitHub server
As an individual profoundly interested in writing highly optimized code and the most concise HTML markup, CSS, and SVG possible, I have been lately trying to optimize the SVG output generated by GIMP of the title of my under development blog.
Although I have been able to eliminate significant number of redundancies from the SVG generated by the GIMP’s path tool, however, when I try to load that SVG from GitHub’s server, it fails to render on my blog’s pages. I am not an expert when it comes to loading SVG from external servers, hence, I cannot comment on the nature of the problem with any degree of certainty. The optimized SVG loads perfectly on all of the mainstream browsers when loaded from my local hard disk — I have Brave, Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Opera, and Tor installed on my device — however, when I try to load it from GitHub’s servers, it fails to display any output. I have tried all of the methods listed in the following three articles to load SVG resources, however, none has produced any desirable results.
If an expert in this field could isolate the problem that is preventing the resource from loading from the GitHub’s server, then I would appreciate the help immensely.

https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg
https://blog.claude.nl/posts/ways-to-use-svg-in-your-html-page/
https://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/`

When I try to load the SVG file directly from GitHub’s server, it loads perfectly on all of the aforementioned browsers. As a nonspecialist or inexpert user of loading SVG resources from external servers, now I have absolutely no clue as to why my resources, which are loading perfectly fine on my device, failing to load or render on my blog’s page. The following direct link from GitHub’s server to the file works perfectly on my device:
I was asked by the moderator of the SVG related section to include a minimum working example for him or others to study the problem. As I could not find the snippet button here in StackOverflow’s editor, hence, I have created a minimum example on CodePen. Take a look and let me know what exactly is the problem.
Codepen Link


body
{
  background: Black;
  border: 2px Solid #454545;
   
}

main
{
  background: Black
  height:   500px;
}

svg
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  
}
   <main>
      <svg viewBox = "0 -150 3000 150">
         <use xlink:href = "#InsightInlined" />
      </svg>
             
      <svg viewBox = "0 -150 3000 100">
        <use href = "#InsightInlined" />    
     </svg>
             
      <svg viewBox = "0 -150 3000 100">
        <use xlink:href = "#InsightInlined" />
        
      </svg>
    
      <svg viewBox = "0 -150 3000 50">
         <use href = "https://rigorous-mind.github.io/SiteSVG/Insight.svg" />
      </svg>
    </main>
    
    <svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox = "0 -150 3000 150">
    
      <g id = "InsightInlined" 
         stroke = "White" stroke-width = "2" fill = "White"
         transform = "scale(.50) translate(0,-650)">
    
       <path id = "LetterICapital"     
       stroke = "White" 
       stroke-width = "2" fill = "White"
       d = "M 113.50,112.50
           V 282 H 142 V 112.50 H 110.50" />
            
       <path id = "LetterN"
          transform = "translate(-2478,0)"
          d = "M 2661.50,158.5 
           H 2639.65 V 282 H 2666.00 V 183
       C 2672.89,175.25 2698.89,175.25 2697.50,193.25
       V 281.50 H 2726.65 V 193 
       C 2729.39,155.5 2684.64,148.5 2665.55,162.90
       L 2665.50,163.00 2661.50,158.50" />
    
       <path id = "LetterS"
            d = "M 342.50,178.50
                C 342.50,178.50 342.50,163.00 342.50,163.00
    329.00,153.00 254.50,144.75 267.50,201.50 279.00,234.25 315.00,225.25 320.75,246.25
    319.50,271.00 282.50,261.50 267.50,261.50 267.50,261.50 268.00,278.50 268.00,278.50
    295.75,286.50 353.50,294.25 348.50,242.00 345.00,220.75 330.75,214.75 303.75,202.75
    285.25,193.75 290.25,169.00 342.25,178.75 z" />
                            
    <path id = "LetterI"
          d = "M 365.00,159
               V 282.25 H 395.00 V 159 
               H 361.50 
               M 395.00,142.00
               V 110.00 H 365.00 
               V 142.00 H 398.00" />
    
             <path id = "LetterG"
                   d = "M 500.75,164.75
                        C 397.25,127.00 411.00,219.00 412.00,244.75
    420.75,294.75 466.25,285.00 471.25,278.75 474.00,312.00 449.00,313.75 420.00,307.75
    420.00,307.75 420.50,324.00 420.50,324.00                     451.25,334.50 501.25,338.25 500.50,273.25
    500.75,273.25 500.75,164.75 500.75,164.75 z
    M 471.50,179.25
    C 471.50,179.25 471.50,259.25 471.50,259.25 464.25,262.00 438.50,274.00 440.50,219.25
    440.00,184.25 446.25,175.75 471.50,179.00 z"/>
                            
    <path id = "LetterH"
       transform = "translate(-4,0)"
       d = "M 524,112.75 524,281.5
            H 552.25 V 182.75
            C 560.75,174.5 581.5,176.75 581.75,190.75
            V 281.75 H 610.25 V 185.67 
            C 606,151.67 568.67,152.67 552.33,160.67
            V 112.75 H 521" />
       <path id = "LetterT" 
            d = "M 635.50,121.25
                 V 160 H 618.25 V 184 
                 H 635.50 V 249.50
                 C 638.5,295.25 684,284.75 700.25,277.5 
                 V 261
                 C 682.75,264.25 662.25,268.5 664.25,241.5
                 V 184 C 678,183.25 688.5,183 696.25,176.5
                 V 160.25 H 665 V 121.25 H 632.50" />
             <use href = "#LetterS" x = "442" />
       </g>
    </svg>



While trying to isolate the problem, I decided to play around with the viewBox settings, and when I set initial y value of the viewBox to -150 or -200, then the browsers start to render the image. It’s startling that the initial viewBox = "0 0 1000 150" or viewBox = "0 0 3000 450" values are not working when I try to load the image inside of the html document. When I load the same .svg image file without the negative value for the first y, it loads perfectly fine as a stand alone SVG file.

when you're using use without a file you're providing an id. When you refer to an external file you've omitted the id. Note that use elements have significant overhead in all browsers. Repeating/duplicating the markup may well be faster depending on your use case.

Robert, when it comes to the  element, how exactly am I supposed to access an SVG element defined within a block at the end of the file. I don’t see why use elements should have a significant overhead in any browsers. As I have studied compilers, hence, I know that back patching is an extremely efficient way to fill the voids in a code file while the parser continues to collect data declared beyond that point which has been marked as missing some data. I really do not see why it should have any significant overhead. On the plus side, it most definitely reduces the size of the file.

the SVG element within the file would need to have an id="something" and then you'd put the something in the reference as you do with internal use elements. Browsers go to an enormous amount of effort to sync use elements in case the content they are pointing to changes.

See view-source:https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20061213/svggen/struct-use-05-b.svg for examples of an external use elements. See how there's a fragment identifier at the end of each reference.

@Irfan Surdar: I've included the codepen as a snippet. Please revise the edit to check if I accidentally removed significant info – you can see changes clicking on the "activity"/version history button)

You're facing multiple problems: 1. as explained by Robert Longson you can only reference elements in a <use> with an ID – you can't load a complete SVGs.  2. You can also reference external SVGs like Insight.svg#InsightInlined – provided the "asset/sprite" svg resides on the same domain.  In other words: it won't work for external domains like github.com – even if CORS header allow cross origin access  3. you could load svgs from external domains via <img> element 4. viewBox values should ideally match the content – otherwise you get undesired padding or cropping.

File size optimisations: focus on coordinate rounding, relative path conversions and shortcuts to reduce markup size. Remaining repetitive code patterns can easily be compressed when serving files with deflate or gzip (supported even on low-cost servers - if not set as default). So you should only choose `' if it significantly improves your development/coding workflow and you can live with the rendering performance "penalty" (negligible when used sparsely).

@herrstrietzel Many thanks for taking the time to turn into an internal Stackoverflow snippet. However, I have not been able to find the button or option in the editor that shows up on my screen when I want to create a snippet. That’s why I created it on CodePen. Would you kindly provide some guidance on how to create the snippet on StackoverFlow? When it comes to information, you probably have not left out anything. Seems complete in the first viewing.

There's  a <> labeled button in the editing toolbar (next to the image con). When you click it you'll see a splt screen for CSS, HTML and JS code - quite similar to codepen or jsfiddle

@herrstrietzel Many, many thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated.
